# How to hide information from user in Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I am looking for a way to hide information from the user but with the ability to reference/use it.

For example - my user selects a specific range with some values, which I want to manipulate further, create new calculations based on that and then reference the data in different parts of the worksheet. I can do manipulations in a different sheet, create some calculations, hide it from the user and so on, but this user might still be potentially able to crack sheet password, unhide sheet and eventually edit this information.

Is there any way to hide this information/calculations "permanently" but still be able to reference/use it?
I have no idea if that is even possible, but my idea was to create some kind of external file (xml?) and store it inside xls/xlsx file (it is a zip after all), but I do not know how to do it, if that is possible, and even if it is possible, how to reference it back and use it inside the file.

Imagine a user who selects the range to create a chart from it. Instead of creating additional data for chart on another sheet, I would like to do it outside of the Excel file and then somehow reference it back and use the data to create aditional chart series (just an example).

Anyone having experience with something similar?

I tagged Excel, VBA, vb.net as I am not sure, which technology might be of help.

Comment: You can look at CustomXMLParts, but anyone who can crack your protection can also view your code, so it will only protect against casual interest...

Comment: @TimWilliams I am aware and I am not that afraid of giving access to code. My whole interest is in simply "making it harder" to access this data. I am well aware that it can be easily cracked, but I am looking for something better than storing this data inside very hidden sheet.

I am not sure if I expressed myself correctly. I will look into CustomXMLParts, but one quick question - can Excel formulas directly reference this data stored using CustomXMLParts? This is my primary goal/objective.

Comment: I'm not certain but I'd guess that any data stored in a customXMLPart is not accessible to formulas unless you were to use VBA UDF which first pulled the data out from the XML and put it into some kind of Global array etc which could be queried.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will research this idea further.

Comment: Does the data you’re attempting to protect actually have to be stored in the worksheet?  Is it feasible to store that info somewhere else?

Comment: @Hursey Not really. Ideally it would be stored inside the Excel file somehow to travel with the file. Again example with charts, where I would store data for the chart somewhere out of reach of my end-user. And I am trying to find that "somewhere" part.

Comment: @RafałKowalski - if you use vba to set an excel sheet to  `xlSheetVeryHidden` then it doesn't even show in the list of worksheets that are hidden in the user interface but you can still reference it and use it through vba

Comment: Well, my opinion is;  If the customer doesn't need to see or consume the data in some way it doesn't need to be there.  If it's in the spreadsheet so the end user can do some sort of analysis, charting, what-if type or it's needed to be consumed by some other 3rd party things then by all means put it in there, but then I would question hiding it if that is the case.